# Swift 3 and lldb: Print frame of UIView, given hex address

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, lldb

Debugging iOS target, Swift 3, Xcode 8.2, lldb-360.1.68

I want to print the `frame` of a UIView whose address I had grabbed at an earlier breakpoint.  Here is my best shot, and the disappointing result:

```
(lldb) expr -l objc -O -- NSStringFromRect((CGRect)([(UIView*)0x7a241b30 frame]))
error: use of undeclared identifier 'CGRect'
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

If you're in the swift debugger you can use [`unsafeBitCast`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1641250-unsafebitcast) to cast your pointer to a type.

```
po unsafeBitCast(0x7a241b30, to: UIView.self).frame
```

Comment: Thank you, @featherless, but this does not work for me.  I presume that by *swift debugger* you mean lldb.  Here is what happens:


`(lldb) po unsafeBitCast(0x7a241b30, to: UIView.self).frame`

`error: use of undeclared identifier 'to'`


Although your usage of unsafeBitCast() appears to be correct according the current Swift 3 documentation, I tried several variations but still get this error error on `to`.

Comment: That's unfortunate! Does lldb autocomplete for you in any manner? You may be on a different version of Swift than what I'm using. Try `unsafeBitCast(0x7a241b30, UIView.self)`.

Comment: I have not seen lldb autocomplete lately.  I just retested with the brand new Version 8.2 (8C38).  I am using Swift 3.  Your previous comment suggests that I remove the `to:` and the `.frame`.  This results in `error: property 'self' not found on object of type 'UIView'`, which of course is even more ridiculous.  Removing the `.self` too results in `error: unexpected interface name 'UIView': expected expression`.  Ah, I think I see the pattern now.  Nothing works :))  Does this work for you, and if so what Xcode and Swift versions are you using?

Comment: Sounds like you're in an unfortunate state for true :) I'm on Xcode Version 8.1 (8B62

Comment: Well, we'll all be using Xcode 8.2 soon.  @featherless, so I can describe any regression when I file a bug in Apple's Bug Reporter, please test if both my command and yours work OK in Xcode 8.1.  MINE:`expr -l objc -O -- NSStringFromRect((CGRect)([(UIView*)0xXXXXXXXX frame]))` YOURS: `po unsafeBitCast(0xXXXXXXXX, to: UIView.self).frame`.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found kind of an answer – more precisely, a *work-less-around*.  **You don't need to print `frame`, or `bounds`, because their values are included in the `description`.**  In this case, just enter

```
(lldb) po (UIView*)0x7a241b30
```

The values of `frame` and `bounds`will be there amid the several hundred lines of stdout you'll get.

I would still appreciate an explanation of why `CGRect` is a *undeclared identifier*, etc.